# Pandas - Searching for terms (irrespective of upper or lower case of the search term)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below code that searches for a string in the entire Dataframe.

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(search)).any(axis=1)]
```

I however have an issue that it fails if the search team is in CAPITAL letter. Is there any way I could search the entire Dataframe irrespective of the search term in Dataframe is in UPPER or LOWER case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need parameter `flags` with `re.I` for ignore cases:

```
import re

df[df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(search, flags=re.I)).any(axis=1)]
```

Another solution is convert each column and also `search` string:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower().str.contains(search.lower())).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df[df.applymap(str.lower).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(search)).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use applymap to apply on each cell of a dataframe.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['this','is'], 'y':['test', 'Hi']})
>>> search = 'HI'
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: search.lower() in x.lower())
       x      y
0   True  False
1  False   True
```

if you need for each row

```
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: search.lower() in x.lower()).any(axis=1)
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```